# Drop column values

Tags: pandas

How can I only keep top 20% (by ascending = False) values from a column in a dataframe?

```
df10 = df9[df9['quality'] > df9['quality'].quantile(0.20)]
```

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quality':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df.loc[df['quality'] > df['quality'].quantile(0.8) , : ].sort_values(by='quality', ascending=False)
```